# If $R$ is a Boolean ring with $\mid R \mid > 2$, determine all the zero divisors of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is a Boolean ring with $\mid R \mid > 2$, determine all the zero divisors of $R$.
My attempt: Let $a, b\in R$, $a \neq 0$ and $ab = 0$. How do I prove that $b = 0$?

Comment: Problem given: find zero divisors of this ring $R$. Approach chosen: suppose $b$ is a zero divisor and prove it is zero. If you look at this summary of what happened, I think you'll agree you need to think about what you are doing a little more thoroughly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $R$ is a Boolean ring, we have $a^2 = a$ for all $a \in R$; since $\vert R \vert > 2$, there must exist an element $a \in R$ with $a \ne 0$, $a \ne 1$.
Then $1 - a \ne 0$, but

$a(1 - a) = a - a^2 = a - a = 0, \tag{1}$

which shows that every $a \in R \setminus \{0, 1 \}$ is a zero divisor.  Since $0$ and $1$ are not zero divisors, the set

$N = R \setminus \{0, 1 \} \ne \emptyset \tag{2}$

is precisely the set of all zero divisors of $R$.

Comment: Does a boolean ring always contain an identity? @Robert Lewis